# Cannot get twig function include to work

Tags: php, twig

So I am building my own framework, purely for learning purposes at the moment

https://bitbucket.org/benshepherd/ben-mvc/src

I have a layouts file, located in `Layouts/default.html`, the view content is loaded through the variable `{{content}}` in the layouts. I am trying to include a navigation bar in the layouts.

```
{% include 'nav.html' %}

//Outputs    
nav.html

{% include 'Layouts/nav.html' %}

//Outputs    
Layouts/nav.html
```

I am new to twig, and can't figure out why it's not working.  Any ideas?

My code:

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';
ComposerAutoloaderInit20fe888ccd463c432bf202972c5e1e6c::getLoader();

// Load your libraries below

//twig
$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
$twig   = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());

//mysql
$dbConn     = new \Simplon\Mysql\Mysql('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$sqlManager = new \Simplon\Mysql\Manager\SqlManager($dbConn);
$sqlBuilder = new \Simplon\Mysql\Manager\SqlQueryBuilder();
```

Comment: What loaders do you have registered?

Comment: Here is the code for that part https://bitbucket.org/benshepherd/ben-mvc/src/95e7c28030759c2b49fca325b972a435394383d2/vendor/autoload.php?at=master

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `StringLoader`, so if you're including files, in fact, you're including strings.

Use the `Twig_Loader_FileSystem` loader instead:

```
<?php

// ...    

//twig
$loader = new Twig_Loader_FileSystem(__DIR__.'/Layouts'); // doublecheck the path
$twig   = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));
```

[Learn more about `Loaders`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#loaders)